# SimpleJSON Unity Exception: Error deserializing JSON. Unknown tag: 123

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm Getting this error when accessing data from a json file.

I'm trying to follow the following tutorial: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

and created a test.json file, that I want to extract data from containing:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "data": {
        "sampleArray": [
            "string value",
            5,
            {
                "name": "sub object"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

using the following code in Unity:

```
void LoadFiles()
{

    FileInfo f = m_info[0]; //Array of Files in Folder
    // I had a foreach loop here, but wanted to specify the file for testing before I tried to parse through one of my own

    print("I Found : " + f);
    var N = JSONNode.LoadFromFile(f.FullName);
    var versionString = N["version"].Value;        // versionString will be a string containing "1.0"
    var versionNumber = N["version"].AsFloat;      // versionNumber will be a float containing 1.0
    var name = N["data"]["sampleArray"][2]["name"];// name will be a string containing "sub object"
    print("vs=" + versionString + " vn=" + versionNumber + " name=" + name);
}
```

and all i get is Unknown tags, from what I gather from the source :

```
public static JSONNode Deserialize(System.IO.BinaryReader aReader)
    {
        JSONBinaryTag type = (JSONBinaryTag)aReader.ReadByte();
        switch(type)
        {
        case JSONBinaryTag.Array:
        {
            int count = aReader.ReadInt32();
            JSONArray tmp = new JSONArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                tmp.Add(Deserialize(aReader));
            return tmp;
        }
        case JSONBinaryTag.Class:
        {
            int count = aReader.ReadInt32();                
            JSONClass tmp = new JSONClass();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string key = aReader.ReadString();
                var val = Deserialize(aReader);
                tmp.Add(key, val);
            }
            return tmp;
        }
        case JSONBinaryTag.Value:
        {
            return new JSONData(aReader.ReadString());
        }
        case JSONBinaryTag.IntValue:
        {
            return new JSONData(aReader.ReadInt32());
        }
        case JSONBinaryTag.DoubleValue:
        {
            return new JSONData(aReader.ReadDouble());
        }
        case JSONBinaryTag.BoolValue:
        {
            return new JSONData(aReader.ReadBoolean());
        }
        case JSONBinaryTag.FloatValue:
        {
            return new JSONData(aReader.ReadSingle());
        }

        default:
        {
            throw new Exception("Error deserializing JSON. Unknown tag: " + type);
        }
        }
    }
```

I'm falling all the way through the Switch, but with .Value or .AsFloat I should hit those case statements. Any Idea what's going on, is this code to old for Unity 5.0 ?

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: It fell through to the line
`throw new Exception("Error deserializing JSON. Unknown tag: " + type);`

Comment: What line of **your code**

Comment: The error was thrown on this line `var N = JSONNode.LoadFromFile(f.FullName);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was under false pretenses, that the JSON file was like XML, text, well it seems it is not, or at least assumed to be binary by SimpleJson when reading files. I tried writing the "Text" to a file, and then reading it and it worked fine. So this is an error where I assumed the data in the examples to be text.

Answer (score 0):

JSONNode.LoadFromFile function instead to JSONNode.Parse(string)  convert stream to string

```
 System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(f.FullName);
 long length = fs.Length;
 byte[] stream = new byte[length];
 fs.Read(stream, 0, (int)length);
 string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream);
 var N = JSONNode.Parse(json);
```